# Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, substring

In a batch file, I have a string `abcdefg`.  I want to check if `bcd` is in the string.

Unfortunately it seems all of the solutions I'm finding search a *file* for a substring, not a string for a substring.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: BTW, it's usually either `Windows` and `cmd` _or_ it's `ms-dos`. MSDOS hasn't been part of Windows for a _long_ time.

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Yes, you can use substitutions and check against the original string:

```
if not x%str1:bcd=%==x%str1% echo It contains bcd
```

The `%str1:bcd=%` bit will replace a `bcd` in `str1` with an empty string, making it different from the original.

If the original didn't contain a `bcd` string in it, the modified version will be identical.

Testing with the following script will show it in action:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set str1=%1
if not x%str1:bcd=%==x%str1% echo It contains bcd
endlocal
```

And the results of various runs:

```
c:\testarea> testprog hello

c:\testarea> testprog abcdef
It contains bcd

c:\testarea> testprog bcd
It contains bcd
```

A couple of notes:

- The `if` statement is the meat of this solution, everything else is support stuff.
- The `x` before the two sides of the equality is to ensure that the string `bcd` works okay. It also protects against certain "improper" starting characters.

Comment: If you're looking on how to do string replacement in a FOR loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6310580/623622

Comment: This is great but I struggled to get this to work when the search value was not a constant (like bcd) but was instead a variable. After much time I finally figured it out. Assuming searchVal has been declared, "x!str1:%searchVal%=!"=="x%str1%"

Comment: @Gary, since that wasn't one of the requirements of this question, you probably should have asked a different question, perhaps linking back to this one as a reference. There's no shortage of people willing to help out. In fact, you still shoud ask that question and answer it yourself (now that you've figured it out) so that it will be useful to future searchers. Self-answering is considered acceptable.

Comment: @gary-brunton, Gary, how did you get the variable search-string to work?

Comment: Gary, I wasn't able to get your variable-search-value working, but this example has it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707742/windows-batch-check-if-variable-starts-with-ends-with-and-contains-a-specific-s

Comment: @MAbraham1 - Here's my new question and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17605406/384853

Comment: Very good solution, but you need to enclose in double quotes or it won't work with variables that have spaces in their values, e.g.: if not "x%str1:bcd=%" == "x%str1%" echo It contains bcd

Comment: "'=str1 was unexpected at this time"

Comment: @BeritLarsen, it would be worth providing a test case for which you get that error you quote, since the code as shown works perfectly with the OP's test data. I notice you've done the same thing to another answer, quoting some error with absolutely zero context or explanation. Without that, you may as well just be saying "lasagna" :-)

Comment: My guess is that *"'=str1 was unexpected at this time"* indicates the command syntax is incorrect (e.g. "IF NOT xPATH:ecs=%==str1" .  It would be great if you pasted your "**if**" statement for us to see.

Comment: Is the *delayedexpansion* a requirement for this to work?  I'm using the statement to set variables and I want to access those variables outside of the *setlocal* code.  I have a work around to do this but it is clunky.

Comment: Note that this method is case insensitive. `(set a=b)&&(echo %a:B=insensitive%)` echos insensitive for me on Win10.

Comment: Any empty or undeclared variable and approach is fallen. Let's use `SET /P str1=<dummyPath\DummyFile.xxx` and we will get `echo was unexpected at this time.`. I'll try to use FINDSTR now.

Comment: if the string has special characters like the ampersand &, you have to double quot both sides of the comparison `"x%str1:bcd=%"=="x%str1%"`

Comment: Down voted. Solution difficult to read with everything so clustered together and was difficult to get this working for me. Preferred the `findstr` solution which did exactly what was needed, neater and easier to follow.

Comment: @Ransom, I've tried to break out the meat of the solution (which is a simple substitution expression rather than all the support stuff I had in the test script) to hopefully make it easier to understand. I still like my solution better since it can easily be done on a single line without invoking any external programs. But, to each their own.

Comment: If the variable might not exist, it is better to check if first with `if "%VAR%" == "" ... `

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. If the variable may not exist you can use the normal method for determining that `IF DEFINED VAR ( ... ) ELSE ( ... )` or `IF NOT DEFINED VAR ( ... ) ELSE ( ... )` instead of checking the contents, because you can actually check IF DEFINED in a loop without delayed expansion enabled. (IE works even on CLI, not just in a batch script)

Comment: `C:\Admin>for /l %l in (1,1,10) DO @(IF NOT DEFINED TESTDef ( ECHO.Not Defined %l & SET "TestDef=%l") ELSE ( ECHO.Defined %l ) )`
Not Defined 1
Defined 2
Defined 3
Defined 4
Defined 5
Defined 6
Defined 7
Defined 8
Defined 9
Defined 10

`C:\Admin>echo %TestDef%`
1


`C:\Admin>for /l %l in (1,1,10) DO @(IF /I "%TESTDef2%" NEQ ""  ( ECHO.Not Defined %l & SET "TestDef2=%l") ELSE ( ECHO.Defined %l ) )`
Not Defined 1
Not Defined 2
Not Defined 3
Not Defined 4
Not Defined 5
Not Defined 6
Not Defined 7
Not Defined 8
Not Defined 9
Not Defined 10
`C:\Admin>echo %TestDef2%`
10`

Comment: Here is, perhaps, even more telling an example of how Defined is a more useful method:
`C:\Admin>for /l %l in (1,1,10) DO @(IF NOT DEFINED TESTDef ( ECHO.Not Defined %l & SET "TestDef=%l") ELSE ( ECHO.Defined %l & SET "TestDef=" ) )`
Not Defined 1
Defined 2
Not Defined 3
Defined 4
Not Defined 5
Defined 6
Not Defined 7
Defined 8
Not Defined 9
Defined 10

Comment: What if the searched value is `:` (column)? Is there an escape caracter?

Comment: Is there another syntax with `!` when used under `EnableDelayedExpansion` ?

Comment: @Sandburg When using inside a loop, use something like the following: if not "x!test:gif=!"=="x!test!" goto :something_end

Comment: `enableextensions` part of the script is unnecessary

Comment: Thank you! This worked inside of a for loop using `"x!str1:bcd=!"=="x!str1!"` instead of `x%str1:bcd=%==x%str1%`.

Comment: If you are trying to do this check on a parameter/argument (like %1) then it doesn't work. You must first `set str1=%1` and then the `%str1:bcd=%` bit will work. I changed my condition to `if "%str1:bcd=%" neq "%str1%"` (double quotes and neq for not equal to) since I think it's a bit more readable. You can also remove `@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion` as it is not needed, unless you're inside a for loop and actually using delayed expansion. The edit queue is full so I'm posting this as a comment.

Answer (score 120):

You can pipe the source string to `findstr` and check the value of `ERRORLEVEL` to see if the pattern string was found.  A value of zero indicates success and the pattern was found.  Here is an example:

```
::
: Y.CMD - Test if pattern in string
: P1 - the pattern
: P2 - the string to check
::
@echo off

echo.%2 | findstr /C:"%1" 1>nul

if errorlevel 1 (
  echo. got one - pattern not found
) ELSE (
  echo. got zero - found pattern
)
```

When this is run in CMD.EXE, we get:

```
C:\DemoDev>y pqrs "abc def pqr 123"
 got one - pattern not found

C:\DemoDev>y pqr "abc def pqr 123" 
 got zero - found pattern
```

Comment: "FINDSTR: Argument missing after /C. got one - pattern not found"

Comment: I was able to easily get this to work inside a for loop, too. I was unable to rework the accepted answer for a for loop (though, I didn't try very hard to see why it didn't work).

Comment: This solution is very easy to read. I recommend checking [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812484/batch-file-test-error-level) for a few gotchas .

Comment: ATTENTION! In some situation, `findstr` doesn't work correctly, for example, `echo c:\_ | findstr /C:"\_"` returns a match, but `echo c:\_ | findstr /C:":\_"` doesn't find a match, nor `echo c:\_ | findstr /C:"c:\_"`. The workaround is to use `find` instead of `findstr`.

Answer (score 65):

I usually do something like this:

```
Echo.%1 | findstr /C:"%2">nul && (
    REM TRUE
) || (
    REM FALSE
)
```

Example:

```
Echo.Hello world | findstr /C:"world">nul && (
    Echo.TRUE
) || (
    Echo.FALSE
)

Echo.Hello world | findstr /C:"World">nul && (Echo.TRUE) || (Echo.FALSE)
```

Output:

```
TRUE
FALSE
```

I don't know if this is the best way.

Comment: I needed to recursively find and compare file names. This was the only solution that worked for me as well! Super handy and very simple.

Answer (score 35):

For compatibility and ease of use it's often better to use FIND to do this.

You must also consider if you would like to match case sensitively or case insensitively.

The method with 78 points (I believe I was referring to paxdiablo's post) will only match Case Sensitively, so you must put a separate check for every case variation for every possible iteration you may want to match.

( What a pain! At only 3 letters that means 9 different tests in order to accomplish the check! )

In addition, many times it is preferable to match command output, a variable in a loop, or the value of a pointer variable in your batch/CMD which is not as straight forward.

For these reasons this is a preferable alternative methodology:

Use: Find [/I] [/V] "Characters to Match"

[/I] (case Insensitive)
[/V] (Must NOT contain the characters)

As Single Line:

```cmd
ECHO.%Variable% | FIND /I "ABC">Nul && ( Echo.Found "ABC" ) || ( Echo.Did not find "ABC" )
```

Multi-line:

```cmd
ECHO.%Variable%| FIND /I "ABC">Nul && ( 
  Echo.Found "ABC"
) || (
  Echo.Did not find "ABC"
)
```

As mentioned this is great for things which are not in variables which allow string substitution as well:

```cmd
FOR %A IN (
  "Some long string with Spaces does not contain the expected string"
  oihu AljB
  lojkAbCk
  Something_Else
 "Going to evaluate this entire string for ABC as well!"
) DO (
  ECHO.%~A| FIND /I "ABC">Nul && (
    Echo.Found "ABC" in "%A"
  ) || ( Echo.Did not find "ABC" )
)

Output From a command:

    NLTest | FIND /I "ABC">Nul && ( Echo.Found "ABC" ) || ( Echo.Did not find "ABC" )

As you can see this is the superior way to handle the check for multiple reasons.
```

Comment: for case sensitivity issue, you can use `setlocal EnableExtensions` then `IF /I` to do case insensitive comparisons.

Comment: That's not really an option because you would still need to isolate the characters for an "IF" Comparison.  IF won't match in "Like" Terms as the OP and particular solutions I replied to are looking for.,

Comment: Hi Ben, Please don't refer to other answers by the number of points they have. That's likely to change. Please update your answer referring to the other answer by that answer's author name, or by a brief phrase describing the technique used in that answer.

Comment: Hi Phone Tagger, that would have been a helpful comment three years ago when I wrote the original post, however as you mention the points values have all changed.  I no longer remember which post I was referring to, and I wouldn't be referring to them by points values today.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I looked around and I believe I was referring to paxdiablo, so I've amended the text to show that.

Answer (score 12):

If you are detecting for presence, here's the easiest solution:

```
SET STRING=F00BAH
SET SUBSTRING=F00
ECHO %STRING% | FINDSTR /C:"%SUBSTRING%" >nul & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO CASE TRUE) else (ECHO CASE FALSE)
```

This works great for dropping the output of windows commands into a boolean variable.  Just replace the echo with the command you want to run.  You can also string Findstr's together to further qualify a statement using pipes.  E.G. for Service Control (SC.exe)

```
SC QUERY WUAUSERV | findstr /C:"STATE" | FINDSTR /C:"RUNNING" & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO case True) else (ECHO CASE FALSE)
```

That one evaluates the output of SC Query for windows update services which comes out as a multiline text, finds the line containing "state" then finds if the word "running" occurs on that line, and sets the errorlevel accordingly.

Comment: You have your IF Statement Backward..  Looking at the original with abcdefg and you flip-flop your logic.  It works.  The way you have it, it does not. `SET STRING=abcdefgh
SET SUBSTRING=bcd
ECHO %STRING% | FINDSTR /C:"%SUBSTRING%" >nul & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO CASE FALSE) else (ECHO CASE TRUE) `

Comment: A +1 is due even though @Leptonator is correct with the inverted logic. This is a simple and easy-to-use solution.

Answer (score 8):

To find a text in the Var, Example:

```
var_text="demo string test"
Echo.%var_text% | findstr /C:"test">nul && (
    echo "found test" 
    ) || Echo.%var_text% | findstr /C:"String">nul && (
             echo "found String with S uppercase letter" 
    ) || (
             echo "Not Found " 
    )
```

LEGEND:

1. `&`   Execute_that AND execute_this
2. `||`  Ex: Execute_that IF_FAIL execute this
3. `&&`  Ex: Execute_that IF_SUCCESSFUL execute this
4. `>nul`  no echo result of command
5. [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
6. `/C:`   Use string as a literal search string

Comment: Can you add some context around your answer please?

Answer (score 6):

I'm probably coming a bit too late with this answer, but the accepted answer only works for checking whether a "hard-coded string" is a part of the search string.

For dynamic search, you would have to do this:

```
SET searchString=abcd1234
SET key=cd123

CALL SET keyRemoved=%%searchString:%key%=%%

IF NOT "x%keyRemoved%"=="x%searchString%" (
    ECHO Contains.
)
```

Note: You can take the two variables as arguments.

Answer (score 6):

**Best approach for me** would be this:

```
call :findInString "HelloWorld" "World"

:findInString
ECHO.%1 | FIND /I %2>Nul && ( 
  Echo.Found
) || (
  Echo.Not found
)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ECHO %String%| FINDSTR /C:"%Substring%" && (Instructions)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for. Explanations are missing, but other comments were helping aswell. Having to check if a substring is *not* in a string goes as `ECHO %string% | FINDSTR %substring% || (when_false)` . The `/C:` modifier isn't mandatory, and beware that `"` around the substring may be looked after.

Answer (score 1):

Better answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46240267/2377343):

```
set "i=hello " world"
set i|find """" >nul && echo contains || echo not_contains
```

Comment: In the question you link using SET is solving a specific and unique need, so there it is important to mention "SET".  However, it does not appear to add anything to the current discussion, as the method of piping a command to the FIND command and testing the result is already provided

Answer (score 1):

The solutions that search a **file** for a substring can also search a **string**, eg. `find` or `findstr`.
In your case, the **easy solution** would be to pipe a string into the command instead of supplying a filename eg.

case-sensitive string:
`echo "abcdefg" | find "bcd"`

ignore case of string:
`echo "abcdefg" | find /I "bcd"`

IF no match found, you will get a blank line response on CMD and %ERRORLEVEL% set to 1

Answer (score 1):

Built on [@user839791](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839791/user839791)'s answer, but I've added a few more things.

```
@echo off
rem --Set variable below--
set var=condition

rem --Uncomment below line to display contents of variable--
::echo The variable is %var%

rem --Change condition to desired string below--
ECHO.%var%| FIND /I "condition">Nul && (  
  rem --Occurs if the string is found--
  Echo.Variable is "condition"
  color C
  pause
) || (
  rem --Occurs if the string isn't found--
  Echo.Variable is not "condition"
  color A
  pause
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, We can find the subString in the String:

```
echo.%data% | FINDSTR /I "POS">Nul && (SET var=POS) || (SET noVar="variable not found")

echo.%data% | FINDSTR /I "TD1">Nul && (SET var=TD1) || (SET noVar="variable not found")

GOTO %var%

:POS   
echo processes inside POS  
GOTO END

:TD1   
echo processes inside TD1

:END
```