# Batch file for loop string replacement

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that take a directory path as a parameter.

In that file folder, there are any number of .ai.pdf or .pdf files that I need to convert to jpg's.  The conversion is not my issue (I am using imageMagick) , but lopping off the full extension is.

I need to be able to either take off the full .ai.pdf (7 characters) or .pdf (4 characters) from the file name and replace it with .jpg  I cannot use just ~n in the for loop because it will not take off the .ai in an instance with there is an .ai.pdf (results in file name.ai where I need just the file name)

There are quite a few posts on StackOverFlow about this 
[StackOverFlow Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file)

but no matter what I attempt to try, I get an error when truncating the appropriate amount of extension off of the file name.

Here is my code. This is the first major batch file I have ever created, so I am open to anything, other than installing more programs to do the work.

The thing that kills me, is I had this working and in the shuffle from one server to another and a week of vacation, the working code got....misplaced.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set dir1=%1
echo recieved !dir1!
for /R %dir1% %%a in (*.pdf) DO ( 
  echo file found !a!
  set b=th_%%~nxa
  if x%b:ai.pdf=%==x%b% set b=%%~dpa!b:~0,-7!
  if not x%b:ai.pdf=%==x%b% set b=%%~dpa!b:~0,-4!

  REM convert -density 64 "%%a" +matte -resize 15%% "!b!.jpg"
  @echo !b! converted
)

ENDLOCAL
```

the file tells me that     **%~dpa!b:~0,-7!** is an invalid substitution

Any ideas?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is about the point at which I'd seriously consider using some other (any other) scripting language. It's really irritating how convoluted it is to do stuff like this in cmd script.

Comment: Use ! variable expansion, not %

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things first:

`!a!` and `%%a` are two different variables.

`if x%b:ai.pdf=%==x%b%` does not mean what you think it does. That will only be true when `%b%` does **NOT** contain `.ai.pdf`.

Again, `if not x%b:ai.pdf=%==x%b%` does not mean what you think. This is true when `%b%` **DOES** contain `.ai.pdf`.

There is no need to do any verification and cutting, just search and replace. ( That is what the `%y:x=z%` notation does, in this example it replaces every `x` within `%y%` with a `z`.)  Let search and replace do the verification. It will only replace what matches the search. That will speed up the your batch file.

Lastly, since you are inside a `()` code block you will need to use the delayed Expansion turned on with your `setlocal` statement. This is because everything inside a code block is treated as if it were on a single line. That means that if you change a variable inside a code block, you will not be able to see the new value using the % notation. Instead you need to replace the `%`'s with `!`'s. For instance...

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set x=Hello
(
  set x=Goodbye
  echo I don't know why you say "!x!", I say "%x%".
)
```

...will give you the old Beatles lyric...

```
I don't know why you say "Goodbye", I say "Hello".
```

---

Anyway, on to your answer:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set dir1=%1
echo recieved !dir1!
for /R %dir1% %%a in (*.pdf) DO ( 
  :: Adding a colon to the end of the filename allows the extension to be ID'd
   : without explicitly looking at it with an IF statement, while simultaneously
  :: avoiding similar looking character groupings inside the filename.
  set b=th_%%~nxa:
  :: No need to check for case, the substitution will do that for you.
  set b=!b:.ai.pdf:=.jpg!
  set b=!b:.pdf:=.jpg!

  REM convert -density 64 "%%a" +matte -resize 15%% "!b!"
  echo %%a converted into !b!
)

ENDLOCAL
```

The drawback is that both the files...

```
X.ai.pdf
X.pdf
```

...will be translated into `th_X.jpg`, creating the possibility of duplicate filenames for two different files.

But that's intrinsic to your concept of treating both types of filenames the same.  If you don't have a method for avoiding this sort of duplication it might not be a bad idea to leave the `.ai` on the file, thereby creating two files: `th_X.jpg` and `th_X.ai.jpg`, eliminating the possibility of duplicate filenames.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of the string replace without having the if check.  It's a clean, understandable, way of doing what I was trying to do.  I would +5 you if I could for the time to explain the %% and !'s.  Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I had to change was to add SET b = %%~dpa!b! to keep the conversion program converting to the same path.  Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hm... would this work for you:
`for /R %F in (*.pdf) do @for %G in ("%~nF") do @echo %~nxF ==^> %~nG.jpg`
(as executed directly from cmd, if run from batch, replace `%` with `%%`).
This has a peculiar effect of changing the case of a file to case of a directory if there exists one with the same name as base name of your file (`file.pdf` will become `FILE.jpg` if you happen to have a subdirectory called `FILE`), but that's it (I think).

This also assumes your base names differ (so no `file.ai.pdf` and `file.pdf` in same directory)

Comment: The drawback to this method is that it will remove ALL "secondary extentions" as well as ".AI".  So **both** `Bla.ai.pdf` and `Bla.anythingAtAll.pdf` will become `Bla.jpg`.