# How do I replace a path subset with another path in a cmd batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

If I have a path
`C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\keyfolder\folder4\file.ext` and a string `keyfolder` which corresponds to one of the subfolders in the path, how can I change the path root up until the `keyfolder` string to have a result such as `C:\newfolder1\newfolder2\keyfolder\folder4\file.ext`?  Basically what I am trying to do is change the folder structure of a file up until a `keyfolder` folder.

```
SET OLD=C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\keyfolder\folder4\file.ext
SET KEY=keyfolder
SET NEW=C:\newfolder1\newfolder2
```

Now I just need to replace `OLD` with `NEW` up until `KEY`.

Thank you!

Andrew

Comment: Do you know how to search for a string? What have you tried?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file

Comment: @Floris that linked helped loads and I managed to figure it out, thanks!

Comment: Great! Why don't you add what you discovered as the answer - it will help other people that have a similar problem, in the future. It's how we all help SO to be the best it can be...

Answer (score 1):

This will work as long as the keyfolder name does not contain `=`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "OLD=C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\keyfolder\folder4\file.ext"
set "KEY=keyfolder"
set "NEW=C:\newfolder1\newfolder2"

set "MOD=%NEW%\%KEY%\!OLD:*\%KEY%\=!"
echo MOD=!MOD!
```