# Not having to have an exact input in Batch

Tags: batch-file

So basicly, is there any way to make it so a Batch file doesnt need an exact answer to do an action. For example:

```
if %c%=images goto :images
```

The above means that I must type in the exact word, `images`, and if I add any more words it wont go to the `:images` label. How would I make it to go to a label using just a word from a sentence that you input.
For example if it asks me:

```
Where would you like to go?
```

And I say:

```
The image section please.
```

Then it takes me to the image section without the need for just saying `image`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find`.

```
echo %c% | find /i "image" >NUL && goto images
```

That'll also provide case-insensitive matching.  Furthermore, you can similarly use `findstr` to match based on a regular expression if you need finer tuning of your match.

If you're curious about how the `|` and `&&` above do their magic, see [command redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

There's a similar question here:  [Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file)

The accepted answer could work in your case:

```
if /i "%c:image=%" neq "%c%" goto images
```

This technique uses string substitution to replace the word `image` with nothing (strip the word from the string you're searching), then compare it to the original string.  If they're different, then the substring was found.