# Find if " - " is in a directory name (batch)

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

In a batch I have a

```
for /d /r %%a in (*) do
```

I want to do an action if %%a contains " - "   (ie white space + hyphen + white space) and another action if it doesn't contain this string.

I cannot make it work! Do you have any idea? Thanks.

[PS : My question is similar to this one : [Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file)  but I'm unable to adapt it to make it work!]

Comment: With  `for /d /r %%a in ("* - *")`,   how to get the part before " - " (as %%b for example)   and the part after " - " as %%c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
for /d /r %%a in ("* - *") do
```

it should work.

Edit: the `for /d /r` loop does only find folders with "`-`" in the **name**, so additional tests for the **path** aren't necessary.

Comment: thanks! how to make a second loop With folders not containing " - " then ?

Comment: You can try this: `for /d /r %%a in (*.*) do set "pname=%%~nxa"&if "%pname: - =%"=="%%~nxa" call ECHO %pname%`

Comment: thanks!

last question : how do I get the **folder name** only of %%a?
example : if `%%a = "d:\blablabla\myfolder12"`  => how to get "myfolder12"?

Comment: try this (from root): `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /s /b "myfolder12"') do set "folder=%%~i"` `echo %folder%`

Comment: thanks again!

if I do `for /d /r %%a in ("* - *")`,   how to get the part before " - " (as `%%b` for example)   and the part after " - " (as `%%c` for example) ?

Comment: Thats a bit more tricky, one example:
`@echo off &setlocal`
`set "fname=bla bla - biz baz"`
`set "right=%fname:* - =%"`
`call set "left=%%fname: - %right%=%%"`
`echo [%left%] * [%right%]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27132/discussion-between-jos-bas-and-endoro)

Comment: Sorry but my time is over, is midnight here ... :)

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work : 

    `for /d %%a in (*) do (`
    `set "fname=%%a"` 
    `set "right=%fname:* - =%"` 
    `call set "left=%%fname: - %right%=%%"` 
    `echo [%left%] * [%right%] )`

Comment: Inside a code block, eg. a `for` loop, you need an other syntax:

`@echo off &setlocal´
`for /d %%a in (*) do (´
`  set "fname=%%~a"´
`  call set "right=%%fname:* - =%%"´
`  call set "left=%%fname: - %right%=%%"´
`  call echo [%%left%%] * [%%right%%]´
`)´

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /d /r %%a IN (*) DO (
 ECHO "%%~nxa"|FIND " - " >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO DO action ONE ON "%%a"
 ) ELSE (ECHO action TWO gets done ON "%%a")
)
```

FIND is used to locate "`-`" in the "leaf" directory, so only if the lowest level contains a "`-`" will action two be performed, else action 1.

If you want it so that a "`-`" occurring ANYWHERE in the filepath makes action two take place, then change `%%~nxa` to `%%a`