# Windows Batch check if variable starts with, ends with and contains a specific string

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd, equals

I'm trying to check if a variable in a batch file starts with `"` contains `BETA` somewhere and ends with `")`.

Is it possible?
And if yes, may somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET var=abc&CALL :check
SET var="abc"&CALL :llcheck
SET var="")&CALL :check
SET var=")"&CALL :llcheck
SET var=abc")"&CALL :llcheck
SET var=xyzbetazyx&CALL :check
SET var="xyzbetazyx"&CALL :llcheck
SET var=xyzbetazyx")"&CALL :llcheck
SET var=xyzbetazyx")"&CALL :check
SET var="xyzbetazyx")&CALL :check
GOTO :eof
:: Lop last, then check
:llcheck
SET var=%var:~0,-1%
:check
SET result=N
SET var2=%var%
SET varvar=%var%

>test1.txt ECHO %var:~0,1%%var:~-2%
>test2.txt ECHO "")
FC test1.txt test2.txt >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO done
SET var|FINDSTR /b "var="|FINDSTR /i "beta" >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO done
SET result=Y
:done
ECHO %var% starts " has BETA and ends ") : %result% 
GOTO :eof
```

Where there's a will...

Setting variables with unbalanced `"` can be tricky. I just set it up balanced and lopped off the last character (`:llcheck` entry : lop last and check.

Essentiall, I've copied the variable into `var2` and `varvar` in oder to demo what happens should these variablenames be set.

Two files are then generated. `TEST1.TXT` contains the first and last 2 character of `var` and `TEST2.TXT` simply `"")`

Compare the two - if they're not identical, then the variable does NOT start `"` and end `")` Otherwise well - could simply have written `var` out to a file and used `findstr` to find `beta`, but I decided to send the output of `SET var` which should be the contents of `ALL` of the `var*` variables in the form

```
var=abc
var2=abc
varvar=abc
```

into findstr, finding the one that starts (`/b`) `var=` and finding whether *THAT* contains the string `beta` The `/i` selects case-insensitive. If you want specifically `BETA` in UPPER-CASE, simply change `beta` to `BETA` and remove the `/i`.

`result` is set to `Y` or `N`

Comment: This certainly works, but there is a much simpler solution using a single FINDSTR regex search. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15730788/1012053)

Answer (score 11):

Assuming your variable does not contain any line feeds or carriage returns, then all that is needed is a single FINDSTR command. It has limited regular expression support that is more than enough for this problem.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set test1=abc
set test2="abc"
set test3="")
set test4=")"
set test5=abc")"
set test6=xyzBETAzyx
set test7="xyz BETA zyx"
set test8=xyzBETAzyx")"
set test9=xyzBETAzyx")"
set test10="xyzbetazyx")
set test11="xyzBETAzyx")

for /l %%N in (1 1 11) do call :test test%%N
exit /b

:test  variableName
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !%1!|>nul findstr /rx \".*BETA.*\") && set "result=PASS" || set "result=FAIL"
echo %1 = !result!: !%1!
exit /b
```

Only TEST11 passes.

The `/R` option forces the search string to be treated as a regular expression.

The `/X` option means it must be an exact match - the entire string must match the search string.

`.*` is the regex wildcard expression that will match any string of characters.

I redirect the FINDSTR output to NUL because we don't need to see the line. We just want the return code

FINDSTR requires double quote literals to be escaped as `\"`

Use delayed expansion so that you can safely echo any value within the variable.

I use `&&` to conditionally take action when FINDSTR succeeded, and `||` to conditionally take action when FINDSTR failed.

My `:TEST` routine takes the name of the variable as the sole argument.

Note that in some situations, the batch parser requires that you also escape the double quote as `^"`, meaning a fully escaped quote will look like `\^"`. But that complication is not needed in your case. The FINDSTR escape rules are actually a bit wonky. See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) for more info.

My test code does a case sensitive search. So `beta` will not match `BETA`. If you want a case insensitive search, then simply add the `/I` option.

***EDIT: 2015-07-22***

Another option, if and only if you want to ignore case, is to use a combination of variable expansion search/replace and expansion substring operations. Both test10 and test11 pass below.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set test1=abc
set test2="abc"
set test3="")
set test4=")"
set test5=abc")"
set test6=xyzBETAzyx
set test7="xyz BETA zyx"
set test8=xyzBETAzyx")"
set test9=xyzBETAzyx")"
set test10="xyzbetazyx")
set test11="xyzBETAzyx")

for /l %%N in (1 1 11) do call :test test%%N
exit /b

:test  variableName
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "result=FAIL"
if "!%1:beta=!" neq "!%1!" if "!%1:~0,1!" equ ^""" if "!%1:~-2!" equ ^"")" set "result=PASS"
echo %1 = !result!: !%1!
exit /b
```

The first IF checks for `beta` anywhere (case insensitive). The second IF checks for `"` at the beginning, and the last IF checks for `")` at the end. The only tricky thing is figuring out how to escape the comparison string when it has an odd number of quotes.

Comment: Excuse me, Dave. Is not an error the right parentheses at `findstr /rx \".*BETA.*\")` ? Yes, it is an old answer, but I just see a link to this topic right now...

Comment: @Aacini - I don't see why you suspect it might be in error. The string never appears within a code block, so the unquoted, unescaped right paren never causes a problem. I have also tested the code, and it works.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps it does not cause an _error_, but I don't see any reason to include a right paren at this place, excepting a typo...

Comment: @Aacini - It most definitely is not a typo - the right paren is there because the OP wants to search for a string that ends with a right paren. The double quotes are escaped (from a FINDSTR point of view), so they are included as part of the search string.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I was confused by the escaped quotes! my fault... :(

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set quote="
set variable="This must be true: BETA")
echo Variable=!variable!
if "!variable:~0,1!" equ "!quote!" (
   rem Start with "
   if "!variable:BETA=!" neq "!variable!" (
      rem Contains BETA
      if "!variable:~-2!" equ "!quote!^)" (
         echo TRUE: it start with " contains BETA and ends with "^)
      ) else (
         echo FALSE, it does not ends with "^)
      )
   ) else (
      echo FALSE, it does not contain BETA
   )
) else (
   echo FALSE, it does not start with "
)
```

Output:

```
Variable="This must be true: BETA")
TRUE: it start with " contains BETA and ends with ")
```

- The way to deal with unbalanced quotes (and with other special Batch characters, indeed) is to use Delayed Expansion: this way the quotes and special characters don't appear in the command line being parsed.
- Remember to escape with ^ any right parentheses that are not closing parentheses of command blocks.
- An easy way to check if a variable contain a given string is try to eliminate the string from variable value: if the result is different to the original value, then the variable contain the string.

Antonio

Comment: Thabks for your answer. It is great too!