# Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file) Part 2 - Using Variables

Tags: string, batch-file, substring, batch-processing, findstr

In a Windows batch file, I have a string 'abcdefg'. I want to check if 'bcd' is in the string, but I also want each to be in a variable, or pass in a parameter for the string.

This solution comes close, but uses constants rather than variables.
[Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file)

Answer (score 8):

try one:

```
set "var=abcdefg"
set "search=bcd"
CALL set "test=%%var:%search%=%%"
if "%test%"=="%var%" (echo %search% is not in %var%) else echo %search% in %var% found
```

```
set "var=abcdefg"
set "search=bcd"
echo %var%|findstr /lic:"%search%" >nul && echo %search% found || echo %search% not found
```

Comment: The second answer here helped me out, I had square brackets in the string and managed to get things working with this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use `FindStr` and the NULL redirect, `>nul`.

```
SET var=%1
SET searchVal=Tomcat
SET var|FINDSTR /b "var="|FINDSTR /i %searchVal% >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo It does't contain Tomcat) ELSE (echo It contains Tomcat)
```

Save as `test.bat` and execute with the parameter to be searched, as follows:  `test Tomcat7`

```
C:\>test Tomcat9
It contains Tomcat
```