# Batch scripting failed string comparison

Tags: windows, batch-file, string-comparison

Debugging the script below "rpmbuild.bat". **NOTE: it contains bugs, not complete**.
This is command line:

```
rpmbuild.bat -bb --target "noarch-pc-windows 7" --buildroot D:\MyPath\MyApp\buildroot --define "_topdir D:\MyPath\MyApp" MyApp.spec
```

The idea is take the above ".bat" cmd parameters, modify them and redirect (via cygwin) to unix tool with the same name (rpmbuild). So to have smth like:

```
bash -c "rpmbuild -bb --target ""noarch-pc-windows 7"" --buildroot /cygdrive/d/MyPath/MyApp/buildroot --define ""_topdir /cygdrive/d/MyPath/MyApp"" MyApp.spec"
```

For transforming paths the proper way, there is an utility **cygpath**.

Below is source of the **rpmbuild.bat**. But it fails to compile on the **line with string comparison** as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file)

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
PUSHD .

SET PARAM_COUNT = 0
FOR %%P IN (%*) DO (
    SET /A PARAM_COUNT += 1
    SET PARAMS[PARAM_COUNT] = %%P

    IF PARAM_COUNT GTR 1 IF PARAMS[PARAM_COUNT-1]=="--buildroot" (
        REM Update buildroot path with cygwin path
        FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('cygpath %%P') do SET PARAMS[PARAM_COUNT]=%%i
    )

    REM string comparison for TOPDIR
    SET str1 = %%P
    IF NOT x%str1:_topdir=%==x%str1% (
        REM Update topdir path
        SET TOPDIR=%%P
        SET TOPDIR=%TOPDIR:~9,-1%
        FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('cygpath "%TOPDIR%"') do SET NEW_TOPDIR=%%i
        SET PARAMS[PARAM_COUNT] = "_topdir %NEW_TOPDIR"
    )

    REM string comparison for .spec
    IF NOT x%str1:.spec=%==x%str1% (
        REM Replace path in spec-file
        SET OLD_PATH=%TOPDIR:\=\\%
        SET NEW_PATH=%NEW_TOPDIR:/=\/%

        sed -s -i -e s/%OLD_PATH%\\/%NEW_PATH%\//g %%P
    )
)

REM construct new rpmbuild command in cygwin

SET RPMBUILD_COMMAND = bash -c "rpmbuild
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,PARAM_COUNT) DO SET RPMBUILD_COMMAND=!RPMBUILD_COMMAND! %%i
SET RPMBUILD_COMMAND=!RPMBUILD_COMMAND!"

REM Execute rpmbuild
%RPMBUILD_COMMAND

POPD
ENDLOCAL
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. here you `SET "str1 "=" %%P"`, two unwanted spaces
2. here `IF NOT x%str1:_topdir=%==x%str1%` you are inside a `for` code block where you need `delayed expansion` `!variables!`, this error occures more often in your script.

Comment: Do unwanted spaces create any issue? IF NOT x!str1:_topdir=!==x!str1!    also does a failure.

Comment: the correct syntax is: `IF NOT "!str1:_topdir=!"=="!str1!"` and `SET "str1=%%P"`

Comment: btw. you can have spaces in variable names in batch. try it: `set "var =17"` next `echo %var%` and last `echo %var %`

Comment: Thanks Endoro. Sorry for late accept. Just finished debugging my script.