# Clearcase: Check if new baseline exists

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I am writing a windows batch script which has a if condition that checks if a new baseline was created i.e. if any new changes were submitted.

I tried:

```
SET REBASE_RETURN="No rebase needed"
SET FLAG=true
for /f usebackq %%F in (`cleartool desc -fmt %%[latest_bls]Cp\ stream:%INTSTREAM%@\%PVOB%`) do ( 
cleartool rebase -baseline %%F@\%PVOB% -complete | findstr !REBASE_RETURN!
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 SET FLAG=false)
```

But this is not working as i expected.

Is there a way i can run a clearcase command, just to get a boolean or some return value. So that i know if a new baseline was created.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- get the foundations baselines of the current stream (from [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm))

  ```
  cleartool descr -fmt "%%[found_bls]CXp\ -cstream
  ```
- for each baselines from Int, check if it is present in the current foundation baselines of Dev.
  See "[Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006016/6309)".

---

For the current baseline: list all the baselines of a stream and take the latest.

```
cleartool lsbl -stream aStream@\aPVob -component aComponent@\aPvob|tail -1
```

(with `tail.exe` coming from the [Gnu On Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki))

Comment: Hi Von. I used the above command to get the foundation baseline. This command gives useful information about the stream. But this doesn't give me the current baseline of my view.

Comment: I am looking for a way to compare the current baseline of my view with the latest baseline.

Comment: @jaggib by "current baseline", I assume the latest baseline (most recent) that you have set on a stream for a component? If so, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sorry to say but I am not getting any output after running the command "cleartool lsbl -stream aStream@\aPVob". No error, no info. I tried running it with -component but i dont think thats applicable in my case.

Comment: @jaggib Well, did you ever make a baseline on that Stream?

Comment: Actually i havent created a baseline on that stream. Its just that i take stream on one of our builder. And if was looking for a way to check if i need to trigger a rebuild on the builder if new baseline was created i.e. baseline newer than the last used baseline.

Comment: @jaggib then my answer stands: if the `lsbl -stream` doesn't return any result, then no baseline newer than the last used baseline has been created.

Comment: Thanks Von. i will check on that and get back. In coming days or so. :)