# Setting environment variable using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to set `PATH` for a tool I wrote using a batch file. But I only want to modify it if the path I want to add isn't already contained in that `String`. I think I get the syntax wrong because I can't get it to work.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set MinGWmsys="%CD%\tools\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;"
set MinGWbin="%CD%\tools\MinGW\bin;"
set SDCCbin="%CD%"\tools\SDCC\bin;"
set lpath="%PATH%"

if not x%lpath:%MinGWmsys%=% == x%lpath% ( 
echo PATH already contained %MinGWmsys%
) else ( 
echo Adding %MinGWmsys% to PATH
setx PATH "%MinGWmsys%;%PATH%"
)

if not x%lpath:%MinGWbin%=% == x%lpath% ( 
echo PATH already contained %MinGWbin% 
) else ( 
echo Adding %MinGWbin% to PATH
setx PATH "%MinGWbin%;%PATH%"
)

if not x%lpath:%SDCCbin%=% == x%lpath% ( 
echo PATH already contained %SDCCbin%
) else ( 
echo Adding %SDCCbin% to PATH
setx PATH "%SDCCbin%;%PATH%"
)

endlocal
```

Can somebody help me here please?

Comment: Consider using `pathman` instead of `setx` as it is specifically designed to manipulate paths and will do most or all of your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x%lpath:%MinGWmsys%=%
```

is parsed as two variables: `%lpath:%` and `%=%`, leaving the string `inGWmsys` as is. Try:

```
echo x%lpath:%MinGWmsys%=%
```

and you will see it.

Instead, you should use

```
if not "!lpath:%MinGWmsys%=!" == "%lpath%" (
```

so that `%variable%` is interpolated before `!another:value=!` (adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file)). I used quotation marks instead of `x` because `if` seems to (mis)interpret `=!` even before the variables are interpolated.

A second problem is the quotation marks:

```
set MinGWmsys="%CD%\tools\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;"
```

should be

```
set MinGWmsys=%CD%\tools\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;
```

because obviously your path does not contain a string `"%CD%\tools\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;"` with quotation marks.

This works:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set MinGWmsys=%CD%\tools\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;
set lpath=%PATH%

if not "!lpath:%MinGWmsys%=!" == "%lpath%" ( 
echo PATH already contained %MinGWmsys%
) else ( 
echo Adding %MinGWmsys% to PATH
setx PATH "%MinGWmsys%;%PATH%"
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Do you know how I have to change it to make it work?

Comment: Just added how to do it at the end of the solution.