# ") was unexpected at this time", Create list of files in a variable - Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I am trying to create a batch file, that gets all the files in `deletesrc` and find's if it's name matches any folder in `deletedest`. To accomplish this, I have tried to generate a list of file names in `deletesrc` which is stored in `deletefiles` (in the format `"first" "second" "third file"`). Then I intend to loop through each folder in `deletedest` and check for it's existence in `deletesrc` (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006016/3492895)). So far I have managed:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "deletesrc=F:\Delete Source"
set "deletedest=C:\Users\Spaced Name\Delete\Dest"

set "deletefiles=" ::I think this is useless, but I would prefer it to be here

for /R "%deletesrc%\" %%i in (*) do (
  set "deletefiles=!deletefiles!^"%%i^" "
  ::random comment that is source of error
)

set deletefiles=!deletefiles!:rTrim

echo !deletefiles!
```

The main problem is, I keep getting `) was unexpected at this time`.

Placing an `echo test` as the first thing within the loop, does not change the output, implying the loop is not run and the error encountered first. Placing an `echo` just before the loop, does produce output and the error immediately after it.

If there are any syntax standards or things I should/should not be doing that do not answer the question, I would like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `::` as a comment inside your `FOR` loop. You can't do this because `::` is actually the label designator and it is breaking the `FOR` loop.

Change this line:

```
::random comment that is source of error
```

To this:

```
REM random comment that is source of error
```

**UPDATE**

As foxidrive stated in the comments, you can use `::` as a comment inside a `FOR` as long as it is not the last line before the closing `)`.

Comment: You can use `::` but not as the last text line before the closing parenthesis, mind you is it wiser not to use it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 set deletefiles=!deletefiles! "%%i"
```

Comment: Then maybe you are adding too many paths\files as a variable can only be around 8 KB long.

Comment: It works here.  Did you use the suggestion I made as it is shown?

Comment: Ok, my fault, I had comments within the ``()`` but I didn't think that would create an error. Can you find out why this happens?

Comment: You waste people's time when you don't show accurate code.  It's the prime sin when asking questions.

Comment: Yes you are right, though I was trying to strip the code down as it is mentioned somewhere on stackoverflow. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction to finding the error, without your stimulus I would not have found it. I would still like you to find out why this happens if possible, I will try to find as well.

Comment: I found the reason (or I think I did), [here](http://blog.crankybit.com/why-that-batch-for-loop-isnt-working/) comment 38. If you could quote that in your answer, I'll give you a well earned upvote + correct answer.