# Windows Batch - check if string starts with ... in a loop

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

this grabs the output from a remote branch list with git::

```
for /f "delims=\" %r in ('git branch -r') do (
::then in here I want to get rid of the origin/HEAD -> line of the output
::and do a few git ops on the other lines, which are the names of branches
)
```

anyhow, I'm finding this frustrating as apparently batch doesn't have regex

here's the code I'm using to do this in bash

```
for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v '\->'`;
do echo $remote; #...git stuff
done;
```

the grep removes the "origin/HEAD -> origin/master" line of the output of git branch -r

So I'm hoping to ask how to implement the 'contains' verb

```
for /f "delims=\" %r in ('git branch -r') do (
if not %r contains HEAD (
::...git stuff
)
)
```

on a loop variable

[this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file) appears to answer a similar question, although in my attempts to implement as such, I became confused by % symbols and no permutation of them yielded function

EDIT FOR FUTURE READERS: there is some regex with findstr /r piped onto git branch -r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=\" %%r in ('git branch -r^|findstr "HEAD"') do (
 echo ...git stuff %%r
)
```

should give you a start.

Note: `%%r`, not `%r` within a batch file - `%r` would work directly from the prompt.

Your `delims=\` filter will produce that portion up to the first `\` of any line from `git branch -r` which contains `HEAD` - sorry, I don't talk bash-ish; you'd need to say precisely what the `HEAD` string you want to locate is.

Use `"delims="` fo the entire line - omitting the `delims` option will set delimiters to the default set (space, comma, semicolon, etc.)

- Don't use `::-comments` within a block (parenthesised statement-sequence) as it's actually a broken label and `cmd` doesn't appeciate labels within a block. Use `REM` comments here instead.

The resultant strings output from the `findstr` (which acts on a brain-dead verion of regex) will be processed through to the `echo` (or whatever statement you may substitute here) - if there are none, the `for` will appear to be skipped.

Quite what your target string would be for `findstr` I can't tell. From the prompt, `findstr /?` may reveal. You may also be able to use `find` (`find /?`) - but if you are using `cygwin` the *nix version of find overrides windows-native.

Comment: This was very useful - I didn't know how to pipe in batch, or about findstr

anyhow, I found the /r regex option on findstr and was able to make a regex which suited my needs

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the git branch output looks like, but with a test case of

```
test 1
HEAD test \-> 2
test 3

test 4
```

the following prints all the text lines except the one containing `\->`

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%r in (d:\test2.txt) do (
    set str1=%%r
   if "!str1:\->=!"=="!str1!" (
       echo %%r
   )
)
```

The if test is fundamentally doing this test: `string1.replace("HEAD", "") == string1`.

Your loop variable needs to be `%r` if used directly in the command prompt, but `%%r` if in a batch file.

The string replacement is a part of environment variables, not loop variables, so it needs to be put into a holding string (str1) to work with. If you have the command extensions enabled ( `enableextensions` ).

And because environment variable setting operations happen when the script is read, you need to override that with `enabledelayedexpansion` and using `!str1!` instead of `%str1%`, otherwise the value of str1 won't change from one loop to the next.

(PS. Use PowerShell instead. `Get-Content D:\test2.txt | Select-String "\->" -NotMatch` ).