# Windows Batch: Assign values from 1 character to another in a string to a variable

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I was wondering how to assign all the text from 1 point in a string to another point in the same string, to a variable.

For example:

```
set special=K
set string=don't_add_meKadd_meKdon't_add_me
```

I was just wondering how to "extract" the add_me and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [substrings](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MidString) to get the part of the string if you know exactly where in the string it is.

```
set string=don't_add_meKadd_meKdon't_add_me
set add_me_part=%string:~13,6%
```

Or, since it seems you're using K as a delimiter, you can use a `for` loop:

```
set string=don't_add_meKadd_meKdon't_add_me
for "delims=K" %%A in ("%string%") do set add_me_part=%%B
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped ALOT. One more question though - do you, or anyone else, know how to test to see if a string has a string/specific text in it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file