# if "filename" contains "variable" do command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm using the windows command line to write my first script. I'm trying to figure out how to run a command if a filename contains a specified variable and if it doesn't then to move on to the next part of the script. The filename Doesn't have to be an exact match, it just has to contain the variable in the specified order. I've been trying all kinds of commands for hours, but to no avail. This is only my second day of scripting so i'm not very knowledgeable on much. I'm looking for a command that will do this...

> if "***[Craig] Christmas Day - 2009 [720p].mkv***" contains "***[720p]***" do ***command***

I know that ***contains*** is not actually part of the **if** command but this is an example i thought would be the easiest to understand.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "thenameofyourfilewhichmaybeinavariable"|find /i "the substring" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo missing) else (echo found)
```

would be the classic way - but there are others.

(the `/i` means "case-insensitive")

see `find /?` and `if /?` from the prompt for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well versed in batch, but a cursory search reveals the [findstr](http://www.computerhope.com/findstr.htm) command. It seems to be capable of basic pattern matching.

If your system doesn't have `findstr` for whatever reason, you can use a messy equality check. Example adapted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file):

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set str1="[720p]"
if not x%str1:bcd=%==x%str1% echo 'It contains [720p]'
endlocal
```