# How to detect if input is quote?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, special-characters

I have the following code

```
if "%userInput%"==""" (
    do_something
)
```

I would like it to detect if the `%userInput%` **is a** quote(`"`). However, this code throws an error.

How to detect if input **is a** quote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution without delayed expansion that should work with any input, including spaces and poison characters. My test code is in a loop. When you are ready to quit, simply press `<Enter>` without typing anything.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:loop
set "var="
set /p "var=enter a string: "
if not defined var exit /b

if "%var:"=""%" == """" echo equals quote

echo(
goto loop
```

The trick should be fairly obvious. Enclose the value in quotes, and double all internal quotes during expansion, such that all token delimiters and poison characters are guaranteed to be quoted. Of course on the right side you must include the enclosing quotes, plus the doubled quote you are trying to match (for a total of 4).

If you need to be able to pass all input (including no value) through the IF test, then you can define a test variable. Something like the following (assume var already has the user input)

```
set "test="
if defined var set "test=%var:"=""%"
if "%test%" == """" echo equals quote
```

**Alternate solution using FINDSTR**

I was inspired by [Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46240267/1012053) to find an alternative solution using FINDSTR that does not require delayed expansion. He interpreted the question differently, answering the question "Does the input value contain a quote anywhere within it?", and solved that using FIND.

But FIND cannot determine if the input exactly matches a single quote character.

A simple one liner with FINDSTR can solve this.

```
2>nul set var|findstr /x ^"var=\"" >nul && echo equals quote
```

or

```
2>nul set var|findstr /x "var=\"^" >nul && echo equals quote
```

Note that FINDSTR generally requires quotes to be escaped as `\"`, and the batch parser requires one of the quotes to be escaped as `^"` because there are an odd number of quotes. If a quote is not escaped, then the remainder of the line is considered to be part of the string instead of redirection and conditional execution operations.

Also note that with the batch parser, it is impossible to escape a quote once quoting is activated. So the following does NOT work

```
2>nul set var|findstr /x "var=\^"" >nul && echo equals quote THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: When I remove the `if not defined` statement, the script still exit when I enter nothing, and throw an syntax error.

Comment: Yes, You cannot execute my IF comparison if the variable is undefined because `"%undefinedVar:"=""%"` expands to `""="""`

Comment: Would this precaution work: setting the `var` to some sort of unused string so it should compare that string, not empty user input.

Comment: I would create another `test` variable so that you don't disturb the original. I'll update my answer

Comment: I tried your updated script, and it works perfectly good except exclamation marks get 'expanded' and become nothing. I have `delayedExpansion` off.

Comment: That can't be. `!` only gets "expanded" if delayed expansion is enabled. `!` within input is preserved when I test my code with delayed expansion off.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. `!` alone works as expected, but `!"` outputs `equals quote`.

Comment: Not in my hands. You must have delayed expansion enabled. Double check your code. Perhaps you should explicitly disable delayed expansion within your code, just in case your command line has it enabled (this could happen inadvertently if a batch script crashes while SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION is active).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154575/discussion-between-stevefest-and-dbenham).

Answer (score 6):

as you asked "if input *contains* a quote". Just `find` it:

```
set "i=hello " world"
set i|find """" >nul && echo yes || echo no
```

Note: `echo %i%|find """"` may not work with unpaired quotes, but `set` doesn't care.

Note the `""""` syntax (looks strange and is unintuitive). `find` doesn't seem to use the usual escaping: `find "^""` gives syntax error.

Comment: The `""""`  syntax is really weird. But according to [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php), `find` do use the uncommon way of escaping.

Comment: +1 Your interpretation is the most common interpretation of "contains a quote". But later on the OP asks "how to detect if input is quote?", which is entirely different. FIND cannot determine if input exactly matches a quote, but FINDSTR can. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46248877/1012053)

Comment: @dbenham @Stephan Perhaps my post `contains` two different questions. Should I change "contains a quote" to "is a quote"?

Comment: @SteveFest - Sure, "is a quote" or "equals a quote" would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 3):

with additional variable and delayed expansion:

```
@echo off

set /p quote=Enter quote
set "test_quote=""
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

if !quote! equ !test_quote! echo equal
```

Comment: Ah! How did I forget delayed expansion when I use it on almost all my scripts :/

Comment: No need for 2nd variable: `if !quote! equ ^" echo equal`

Answer (score 2):

…and possibly without delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "input=Please input a character: "
If [^%input%]==[^"] (Echo it is a quote) Else Echo it is something else
Timeout -1
```

Comment: if your input contains space the script will fail

Comment: @Compo I once considered your method, but noticing that this will fail on input with space and special characters. *Keyboard cats are everywhere.*

Comment: The question was about checking a quote as a single character, not a series of characters, you could for instance use `If [^%input:~,1%]==[^"]` to check a specific character. If the character is a space that could be catered for in a separate `If`, but is outside of the scope of the question. My answer was not given as a generic robust solution, just an alternative to show that enabling delayed expansion is not the only solution just the best one.

Comment: @Compo Your last comment is correct indeed. I also understand the I asked for checking only 1 character. Your example is also a good one since it is delayed expansion free and doesn't have to worry about the input `!` in other places of my script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it with enabledelayedexpansion

I am unsure if this would work without delayedexpansion

if "!_my_input_char!"==^"^"^" echo this was a doublequotes character

This appears to work correctly no matter what single character is inside of _my_input_char