# Search string for trailing quote character and trim it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, double-quotes

I'm trying to search a string (entered by the user when prompted for a path) for a trailing quote and delete it if found.

The problem: I have a bat file that prompts the user to enter a filename and path (the first is typically done via drag/drop.) If the user enters a destination path enclosed in quotes because it contains spaces, my resulting command will look like this: `compress.exe "c:\source path\"destination.zip"`

That extra quote in the middle needs to go. I've found plenty of ways to search a *file* for a string, and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file) here on StackOverflow that seems to apply, but doesn't seem to work in my situation.

I tried the command at the above linked path, telling it to search for `\"` instead of `bcd`, but the code expects the string it's searching to have been passed to it (as a switch) upon execution, and when I try to modify the command to search **srcpath** instead, the bat fails. I also tried this:

```
if "!srcpath:~-1"=="\"" set srcpath=!srcpath:~0,-1!
```

This results in: "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

How can I search a string for a trailing quote and trim it? Every method I can find doesn't seem to work when the character being searched for is the quote (slash quote: `\"`).

Comment: If you know they are putting a leading and trailing quote just strip both of them. `for /f "useback tokens=*" %%G in ('%srcpath%') do set srcpath=%%~G`. Then your other command looks like this: `compress.exe "%srcpath%destination.zip"`

Comment: Nice Squashman..  I too thought of this.  ;^)  I showed my 'hack way' because it can be used to strip all sorts of things where "~" only strips quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a SLOPPY batch trick when working with paths just for this reason.
There are more elegant ways but this works just as well and I don't ever have to remember how I pulled it off.

First of all, 90% of the time.. we just want ALL quotes stripped.. that would just be:

```
set srcpath=%srcpath:"=%
```

Then tack quotes on to the front and back of your new concatenated path string.

**But if you REALLY only want the trailing one..** here is my stupid bash trick..

```
1. Add a "? to the end of your string
2. Then delete ""? from that string
3. Then delete "? from that string
```

Wella!  Never fails!
The trick here is that a question mark isn't a valid path char.

```
:: SAMPLE -- Just a trailing quote removed
set srcpath="c:\source path\"
set srcpath=%srcpath%"?
set srcpath=%srcpath:""?=%
set srcpath=%srcpath:"?=%
echo srcpath=%srcpath%

::You can use the SAME TRICK to remove a trailing backslash
```

Comment: Thanks. The "=% method appears to work. I'm not quite sure how or what it does, but as long as it works. Thanks. :)

Comment: You are welcome but I expected to get the check since I submitted the same exact solution the day before.

Comment: How does it work?
%MY_VARIABLE:SEARCH_THING=REPLACE_THING%
In this case REPLACE_THING was nothing so :"=% is replace quote with nothing.

Comment: Sorry on the Check I couldn't tell who replied first. The one I checked said "one day ago" while your said "18 hours ago".

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
SET /P "%SRCPATH=Enter the source path "
ECHO %SRCPATH%
ECHO %SRCPATH:"=%
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Is the closing **%** part of the method or can I use **"=** elsewhere?

Comment: The final % is required to specify the end of the variable. The third (3rd) line does a string replacement of `"` with nothing. I am not sure what you mean by "use = elsewhere."