# if statement executing if "value" is found in file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I want to find every line in a text file that contains the word "foo".  I set up my if statement like this...

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%textfile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


    set "wordtofind=foo"
    if not "!line!"=="!line:!wordtofind!!" (
        set "erase=!line:*=!"
        set "newCode=bar"
        >>"!textfile!" echo !newCode!
```

For some reason, the if statement executes when the string "value" is found.  Can someone please explain why that is?

Comment: What do you think `!line:*=!"` will do? Or `!line:!wordtofind!!`?

Comment: I'm new to batch but I thought that it would find "foo" erase the line and then replace it with "bar".  But it also finds lines with the string "value" and replaces them with "bar".

Comment: I would suggest you forget about using a batch file and choose a language/utility which can modify files directly, will accept regular expressions and where poison characters are less of an issue.

Comment: Great suggestion... but this has to be in a batch file.

Comment: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` must be put before a code block. You enabled it when the whole `for /f` block has been passed through variable substitution, which is useless

Comment: I now have setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at the top of my code and it still does not work.  I also replaced % with !.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I found what I needed here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file/7006016#7006016