# Delete all files in a folder except those with names containing

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to delete all files in a folder EXCEPT those whose filename contains the string `ntdll`.

Here's what I have tried:

```
for %i in (dlls/*) do if not %%i == %%i:ntdll del %%i
for %i in (*) do if not %i == %i:ntdll del %i
```

I tried with `findstr` but I had little success.

Comment: You tagged this question as a batch-file but your code clearly shows that you are only running it from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Here is a possible solution (you will need delayed expansion):

```
for %A IN (*) do @set file=%A && if !file!==!file:ntdll=! (@del /F /A !file!)
```

Enable delayed expansion in cmd with `cmd /v:on`. You are forced to use it as you are inside a code block.

This simple command searches for all files in the current working directory, assign each in a variable and checks if they have the string `ntdll` inside them. If not, they delete them.

For better understanding commands mentioned above, open a new cmd and type:

- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `del /?`

Some interesting references for further reading

- [Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file)

Comment: It's good of you to change your answer following my comment, however I'd have preferred it had you responded to let me know, so that I could have deleted the comment. But whilst I'm here, I must ask, have you actually read the output from `Del /?` as you've advised the OP to do? I ask because, you are now using the `/Q` option, despite deleting individual files one by one. The `/Q` option as far as I'm aware is used when specifying a 'wildcard', you haven't used a wildcard and therefore don't need that option at all. Can I also ask why you you decided against using the `/A` option I advised?

Comment: It works in the same manner as the `Dir` command! If you use `/A` without specifying attributes, `Del` displays the names of all files, (i.e. it assumes all attributes, `/A:RHISAL`, _where the colon, **`:`**, is optional_).