# Remove duplicates from comma separated list in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that (among other things) turns a list like this:

```
'foo_ph1-1.tif', 'foo_ph2-1', 'foo_ph2-2'
```

into a list like this, in a local variable called `INVNOS`:

```
'fooph1', 'fooph2', 'fooph2'
```

I want to remove the duplicates from the second list. I've been trying to do this when I create the list, from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7005951/1016065I), to no avail.

Here's how I make the list.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in ("*.tif") do @echo %%~nf>>list.lst
set FNAMES=
set INVNOS=
for /f %%i in ('type list.lst') do (
    set FNAMES=!FNAMES!'%%i.jpg', 
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%a in ("%%i") do (
        set BEFORE_HYPHEN=%%a
        set INVNOS=!INVNOS!'!BEFORE_HYPHEN:_=!', 
    ) 
)
set "FNAMES=%FNAMES:~0,-2%" 
set "INVNOS=%INVNOS:~0,-2%"
echo %INVNOS%
endlocal
```

Solutions with `findstr` won't work because I need to initialize `INVNOS` with an empty string, and I get stuck with the difference between `%` and '!', and slicing, inside the `for` loop.

I know this is easy in Python, however I'd like to do it with what's native (Windows 10/Windows Server), so CMD or Powershell.

Any suggestions?

Just to sketch the bigger picture, `INVNOS` (inventory numbers) is derived from directories full of tif's, so we can check whether or not they exist in some sql database.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Did you intend for the second item in the example input be `'foo_ph2-1'` instead of `'foo_ph2_1'`?

Comment: @aschipfl You are correct (or you may be fishing for views to your blog, or both), but the term DOS is well established, in the same way that the Save icon is well established, when whole generations have never witnessed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach the problem differently:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in (*.tif) do (
  for /f "delims=-" %%g in ("%%~nf") do set "~%%g=."
)
for /f "delims=~=" %%a in ('set ~') do set "INVOS='%%a', !INVOS!"
set "INVOS=%INVOS:~0,-2%
echo %INVOS:_=%
```

The trick is to define variables for each filename (the variableNAMES contain the filenames. A variable can only exist once, so per definition, there are no duplicates)

With another `for` loop extract the names from the defined variables and join them. The underscores can be deleted in one go instead of removing them from each substring.

When needed, you can delete the variables with `for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set ~') do set "%%a="`, but they are destroyed anyway when the script ends. (same line when you want to be sure, no variable starting with `~` is defined by accident before you set them)

Comment: Very nifty, danke dir! I was puzzled about `'set ~'`, but I think it's all local variables starting with `~`, right?

Comment: The `set "~%%g=."` in line 4 needs the final dot (`.`). Could you explain why, or point to documentation please? Hard to find googling.

Comment: no, it doesn't (specifically) need a dot - it just needs to not be an empty string. (We don't use the *value* of the variable here, but the variable*name* itself, so we have to assign anything to the variable (because in batch, a variable with no value is not existent, a concept antithetical to most programming languages))

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to step up to PowerShell, something like this could be done in a .bat file script. Of course, It would be easier to write and maintain if it were all written in PowerShell.

=== doit.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.tif' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { '''' + $($_.Name.Split('-')[0].Replace('_','')) + '''' } |" ^
        "Sort-Object -Unique) -join ','"') DO (
    SET "INVNOS=%%~A"
)
ECHO INVNOS is set to %INVNOS%
EXIT /B
```

Get-ChildItem produces a list of all the *.tif files in the directory. Split() does what "delims=-" does in a FOR loop. The [0] subscript chooses everything up to the first '-' character in the file name. Replace will remove the '_' characters. Sort-Object removed duplicates to produce a unique list. The -join converts the list of names to a single, comma delimited string. The resulting string is stored into the INVNOS variable.

Do you really want APOSTROPHE characters around each name in the list?

Comment: Yes, I really want apostrophe around each name, because `echo select term, priref from table_name when term in (%INVNOS%)>query.sql` won't work otherwise. You're right about Powershell, but I don't know where to begin. It _is_ a bat file script. Windows bat file script. .

Comment: @RolfBly, APOSTROPHE characters have been added.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Minor detail: when I run this in a cmd prompt, it resizes the window and changes the font. Any idea? Default settings for PowerShell and CMD are identical.

Comment: I have seen that problem in the past, but I no longer have it and do not know what made it go away. That would be a question for https://superuser.com/ Does this code do what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, it does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: The values assigned to these variables suit my system and test environment
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "tempfile=%temp%\tempfile.txt"

:: remove variables starting :
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set : 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
(for %%f in ("%sourcedir%\*.tif") do echo %%~nf)>"%tempfile%"
set "FNAMES="
set "INVNOS="
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("%tempfile%") do (
    set FNAMES=!FNAMES!'%%i.jpg', 
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%a in ("%%i") do (
        set "BEFORE_HYPHEN=%%a"
        SET "before_hyphen=!BEFORE_HYPHEN:_=!"
        IF NOT DEFINED :!BEFORE_HYPHEN! set "INVNOS=!INVNOS!'!BEFORE_HYPHEN:_=!', "&SET ":!BEFORE_HYPHEN!=Y"
    ) 
)
set "FNAMES=%FNAMES:~0,-2%" 
set "INVNOS=%INVNOS:~0,-2%"
echo %INVNOS%

IF DEFINED tempfile DEL "%tempfile%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the value assigned to `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.

`%tempfile%` is used temporarily and is a filename of your choosing.

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

it is standard practice on SO to use the syntax `set "var=value"` for string
assignments as this ensures stray trailing spaces on the line are ignored.

Evil trailing space on OP's code `set INVNOS...` within the `for ... %%a` loop.

Given OP's original filename list, `foo_ph1-1.tif foo_ph2_1 foo_ph2-2`, the processing should produce `fooph1 fooph21 fooph2`, not `fooph1 fooph2 fooph2` as claimed.

My testing included `foo_ph2-2.tif`

The code is essentially the same, but first clearing any environment variables that start `:`, on the Irish principle.

The temporary file nominated is recreated avoiding the (unfulfilled) requirement to first delete it.

`BEFORE_HYPHEN` is explicitly expunged of underscores before the `if not defined` test is applied. I selected `:` because `:` can't be part of a filename. Once the name is applied to the `invnos` list, the `:!BEFORE_HYPHEN!` variable is established to prevent further accumulation of repeat `BEFORE_HYPHEN` values into `invnos`.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate solution. "Evil trailing space", good point, accepted. `foo_ph2_2` should be `foo_ph2-2`, was edited.